# Django context_processor no module named

Tags: python, django

I want to use a context_processors for my base.html template.
You can see my project structure in the following picture:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FFRF.png)

```
from difoni_forms.DIFONIAPP.models import Admin


def check_active(request):
    return {"active" : Admin.objects.get(id=1).active}
```

This is the code from my context_processors.py.And I added this line of code to my settings  `'DIFONIAPP.context_processors.check_active'`

When I run the program i get the following error:
No module named 'difoni_forms.DIFONIAPP'.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong any helpis appreciated, ty in advance.

Comment: Your imports are probably off. Try changing from `difoni_forms.DIFONIAPP.models` import Admin
 to `from DIFONIAPP.models import Admin` and see if that fixes it. Also, it's general convetion to have lowercase app names, something like `difoni` instead of `DIFONIAAPP`. Hope this helps1

Comment: You were correct about the import being wron i changed it to ```from .models import Admin``` and now everything works. Also ty fo rthe convention hint, I'm a newbie so all tips are appreciated. You saved me a lot of time, big thanks.

Comment: You got it, these little things are the most annoying. Best of luck!